# WSO2 ESB - Accessing WSDLs, XSDs and XSLTs from ESB directory

Tags: wso2-esb

We are trying to implement proxy service using WSO2 ESB (4.8.1). The proxy service implementation needs to access wsdls, schemas and xslts.

One option is to put these artifacts in Governance registry. However, we are not planning to connect ESB with database (which is recommended for governance registry). In that case, is there a way I can refer to these files that are residing in the file system along with other ESB artifacts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept call [Deployment Synchronizer based on SVN](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Introduction+to+Deployment+Synchronizer). Deployment Synchronizer provides capability to synchronize deployment artifacts across the nodes of a product cluster.